# Howto get rid of [WARNING] Deprecated API called in maven site

Tags: java, maven-2

I like to get rid of the following warning while calling `mvn site:site` on a project

```
[INFO] Generating "About" report. 
[WARNING] Deprecated API called - not org.apache.maven.doxia.sink.Sink instance and no SinkFactory available. Please update this plugin. 
[INFO] Generating "Issue Tracking" report. 
[WARNING] Deprecated API called - not org.apache.maven.doxia.sink.Sink instance and no SinkFactory available. Please update this plugin. 
[INFO] Generating "PMD Report" report. 
[WARNING] Deprecated API called - not org.apache.maven.doxia.sink.Sink instance and no SinkFactory available. Please update this plugin. 
[WARNING] Unable to locate Source XRef to link to - DISABLED 
[INFO] Generating "Continuous Integration" report. 
[WARNING] Deprecated API called - not org.apache.maven.doxia.sink.Sink instance and no SinkFactory available. Please update this plugin. 
[INFO] Generating "Source Repository" report. 
[WARNING] Deprecated API called - not org.apache.maven.doxia.sink.Sink instance and no SinkFactory available. Please update this plugin. 
[INFO] Generating "Project License" report. 
[WARNING] Deprecated API called - not org.apache.maven.doxia.sink.Sink instance and no SinkFactory available. Please update this plugin. 
[INFO] Generating "CPD Report" report. 
[WARNING] Deprecated API called - not org.apache.maven.doxia.sink.Sink instance and no SinkFactory available. Please update this plugin.
```

The  part of my pom looks like this:

```
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <reportSets>
          <reportSet>
            <reports>
              <report>index</report>
              <report>cim</report>
              <report>issue-tracking</report>
              <report>license</report>
              <report>scm</report>
            </reports>
          </reportSet>
        </reportSets>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
      </plugin>            
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
```

My `mvn --version` returns the following output:

```
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-06 21:16:01+0200)
Java version: 1.6.0_10
Java home: /opt/jdk1.6.0_10/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux" version: "2.6.32-41-generic" arch: "i386" Family: "unix"
```

Unluckily I'm unable to find the correct plugin that cries for an update. Updating/Migrating to maven-3.x is not an option at the moment.

Comment: Why are you calling mvn site:site instead of mvn site ? Furthermore why is an update to Maven 3.0 no option? The only big difference between MVN 2.2.1 and 3.0.4 are the site generation part which seemed to be under construction..

Comment: mvn site:site displays the same warnings so far. Maven can't be migrated at the moment, since my company is bound by policy to this version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem last week. The problem its on the maven-site plugin which is not using the correct version.
This is what I did:

pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
</plugin>
```

Finally to select the reports, I use the `<reports>` section:

```
<project>
...
<plugins>
<reporting>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <reportSets>
      <reportSet>
         <reports>
       <report>index</report>
       <report>project-team</report>
           <report>issue-tracking</report>
       <report>summary</report>
     </reports>
      </reportSet>
    </reportSets>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</reporting>
...
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the [maven-site-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/migrate.html) to version 3.1. cause you can use the newer version for Maven 2.2.1 as well.

Comment: I'm not sure, if I did that corretly... I simply changed the <version>2.4</version> tag to <version>3.1</version>. Maven downloaded the newer version and showed me the same errors as mentioned in my question.

Comment: Do you have a pluginManagement section somewhere? If yes define the version in the pluginManagement.

Comment: At the moment I do not use `<pluginManagement />` somewhere. The sole place where version is in the plugin section below `<reporting />`.

Comment: Have you defined a plugin like the project-info-report plugin at a second place in your pom?

Comment: No. The `<reporting />` section is the only place where I specified this.